# Joining two tables on different database servers

Tags: sql

I need to join two tables `Companies` and `Customers`.

`Companies` table is in **MS SQLServer** and `Customer` table is in **MySQL Server** .

What is the best way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: In .net I would use a dataset object to do this. In Java after a short research there is a class almost same as dataset in .net - resultset, probably you can look into the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understand correctly, you need to join tables in SQL Server, not in code, because tag is `sql`.

If I have right, then you need to do some administrative tasks, like server linking.

[Here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008) you have an explanation how to link MySQL server into MSSQL server.

After you successfully link those servers, then your syntax is simple as:

```
SELECT 
    [column_list]
FROM companies
    JOIN [server_name].[database_name].[schema_name].[table_name]
WHERE ...
```

Keep in mind that when accessing tables that exist on linked server, then you must write four-part names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Companies from DB1
2. Select Customers from DB2
3. Put them in `Map<WhatToJoinOn, Company>` and `Map<WhatToJoinOn, Customer>`
4. Join on map keys, creating a `List<CompanyCustomer>`

Comment: It's 2 different database server.

Comment: Exactly, this answer doesn't deserve a downvote. I added this to the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In order to query 2 databases, you need 2 separate connections. In this case, you would also need separate drivers, since you have a MSSQL and a MySQL database. Because you need separate connections, you need 2 separate queries. Depending on what you want to do, you can first retrieve your `Companies` and then do a query on `Customers WHERE company = 'some value from COMPANIES'` (or the other way around).

You could also just fetch every row from both tables in their own lists and compare those lists in your code, rather than using a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1 retrieve the data from Companies table from the SQL server and store the required columns in an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` format.

Therefore creating rows as arraylist index and HashMap as the key value pair responding to column names. Key: column name and Value as column value of that row.

2 Then pull data from Customer tables adding a where clause by converting data from your first Map into a comma separated format. Thus creating a filter similar to the join in SQL.

Add the data to the same result set data as before thus not over lapping the column names in the HashMap.

when u need to access the 5th row column7 then u write

ArrayList.get(4).get("column7");

The logic is given, Please implement it yourself.